# Using Mockk to mock out a singleton object to ignore Auth journey

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk

I am using Mockk and I have the need to intercept when an API client is being created.

The API client does a bunch of REST stuff that I don't want to happen inside of its constructor. I have tried a bunch of things but can't seem to find a way to not actually run the constructor and just return something.

I don't want to actually run anything when the object is created. Is this possible?

I've tried:

Class I want to mock:

```
class TestApi(config) {
   auth = Auth.authenticate(config) // Don't want this specifically to run
}
```

Caller:

```
fun createClient() {
    return TestApi(ConfigObj())
}
```

Then in the test

```
@Test
fun `sample code`() {
  mockkConstructor(TestApi::class)
  every { anyConstructed<TestApi>() } returns FakeInstance()
  
  // other test stuff always fails as TestApi() still runs the full init with the auth flow
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is mocking out the undesired authentication journey for the scenario you're trying to test.

Given that the authenticate method is either a singleton or a static (JVM) method, then what you need is:

[Mockk - Singleton objects and static methods feature](https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/mocking/static/).

Let's see an example on a singleton object since this is Kotlin:

Given that I have the following Auth object that will always fail when ran:

```kotlin
object Auth {
    fun authenticate(config: Any): Unit =
        error("I will always fail if you don't mock this method out...")
}
```

And I have the following API I want to test:

```kotlin
class API(config: Any) {
    // This call will always fail...
    val auth = Auth.authenticate(config)
}
```

Then you can safely mock out the singleton by using [`mockkObject`](https://mockk.io/#object-mocks):

```kotlin
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockkObject
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertDoesNotThrow
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows


internal class SingletonObjectMocking {
    @Test
    fun `should fail if authenticate is not mocked out`() {
        assertThrows<IllegalStateException> { API(Any()) }
    }

    @Test
    fun `should ignore auth flow by object mocking Auth`() {
        mockkObject(Auth) {
            // This is where we mock out the authentication flow
            every { Auth.authenticate(any()) } returns Unit
            assertDoesNotThrow { API(Any()) }
        }
    }
}
```

When you place the mocked behaviour within the lambda, the logic will be unmocked after the block has been executed. This convenient for single tests as otherwise you will need to explicitly call `unmockObject(Auth)` (or `unmockkAll()`).